# list of integer square roots python

Tags: python, filter

Chances are this is a duplicate question but I've looked through the duplicate questions and I don't see an answer for python.

I'm trying to create a simple program where I can hard code a list of integers and filter out all the numbers that have integer square roots.  Here's what I have so far:

```
# Python Program to display the number of integer square roots in a list
import math

# Change this list for testing
terms = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,16,24,36]

all_roots = []  #list to hold all square roots from terms list

for i in terms:
    all_roots.append(math.sqrt(i))

#integer_roots = list(filter(lambda x: [????], all_roots)) #not sure what I should put in the "[????]" part

print(all_roots) #prints integer and floating square roots
print(integer_roots) #supposed to print only square roots that are integers
```

To clarify, `print(all_roots)` currently displays:

```
[1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.449489742783178, 2.6457513110645907, 3.0, 3.1622776601683795, 3.3166247903554, 3.4641016151377544, 3.605551275463989, 4.0, 4.898979485566356, 6.0]
```

But I want `print(integer_roots)` to display

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: (You could format your code outputs using four spaces "    " instead of quotes ">". Just like you did in the first part :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import math
terms = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,16,24,36]

integer_roots = [] 

for i in terms:
    tmp = math.sqrt(i)
    if (tmp.is_integer()):
         integer_roots.append(int(tmp))

print(integer_roots)
```

Comment: Don't call `sqrt` twice, store the result instead

Answer (score 6):

A list comprehension would help with a generator expression inside to prevent duplicate function calls:

```
>>> [int(i) for i in (math.sqrt(i) for i in terms) if i.is_integer()]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Or if you want a purely functional approach, since you suggest using `filter()` in your post:

```
>>> list(map(int, filter(float.is_integer, map(math.sqrt, terms))))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Of course this can be written out with a regular `for` loop, which is less performant but totally acceptable, particularly given the OP seems new to Python:

```
lst = []
for i in terms:
    s = math.sqrt(i)
    if s.is_integer():
         lst.append(int(s))
```

Comment: those two for statements next to each makes it hard for my beginner's brain to understand.  I thought I understood list comprehension...

Comment: and that's a map within a map.  wow. lot's of studying to do.

Comment: @MountainScott I wrote it out with a loop to, which will hopefully help you understand it better :)

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to write it that way but, yes, I understand now :) @Chris_Rands

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the first example (I guess it's better to read it from the inside out).  I mostly get the second example but your use of "float" confuses me. You're calling the float function even though the values returned from math.sqrt are already floating point numbers? @Chris_Rands

Answer (score 0):

import math
arr = list(map(math.isqrt ,[1,2,3,4]))
print(arr)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).